# what s+ S1+ T R+ mean in ps ax ps list

Tags: ubuntu, ps

I run this command and got result this but not able to understand the result  which node instance should i kill

```
 ps ax | grep node


23308 pts/3    S+     0:00 sudo node index.js
23310 pts/3    Sl+    0:00 node index.js
23568 pts/1    T      0:00 sudo node index.js
23824 pts/4    S+     0:00 sudo node index.js
23826 pts/4    Sl+    0:00 node index.js
24202 pts/5    R+     0:00 grep --color=auto node
```

and what S+ Sl+ T, R + Means .?

Answer (score 75):

These are process STATE codes - from the [**man page**](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps)

```
PROCESS STATE CODES
       Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output
       specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe the state of
       a process.
       D    Uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
       R    Running or runnable (on run queue)
       S    Interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
       T    Stopped, either by a job control signal or because it is being
            traced.
       W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
       X    dead (should never be seen)
       Z    Defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its
            parent.

       For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional
       characters may be displayed:
       <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
       N    low-priority (nice to other users)
       L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
       s    is a session leader
       l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
       +    is in the foreground process group
```

Comment: So what is the diff between S+ and S1+ ?

Comment: @Antarus I believe its `Sl+` and not `S1+`. Meaning its in interruptible sleep, foreground process group and multi-threaded.